# How to mount the shared directory in samba server with writable permission?

Tags: mount, permission-denied, samba

Create a directory:

```
mkdir  /tmp/shared
```

Mount the directory in samba server:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=smb  //192.168.31.21/shared    /tmp/shared
Password for smb@//192.168.31.21/shared:  ***
```

It is mounted, and can list all files in it:

```
ls  /tmp/shared
```

The file can't be saved after editing it - error:

```
Failed to save the document
permission denied
```

How to mount the shared directory in samba server with writable permission?

Comment: Do you need access with login+password. If ynot you could try samba config with anonymous users access: https://gist.github.com/EvilLord666/a9943d873f8a700a0175024f3968acc2

Comment: As far as I understand, all the command lines shown here are executed on the client side. What it is the samba configuration on the server (192.168.31.21) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have set `writeable = yes` in your  `/etc/samba/smb.conf`

To allow all users to access and write:

```
 [share]
 path = /shared
 browseable = yes
 read only = no  
 writeable = yes
 browseable = yes
 public = yes
 create mask = 0644
 directory mask = 0755
```

Depending on your distro `/etc/init.d/samba restart` or `systemctl restart smb`